# Display post list by custom post type and category

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Hi i need to display list of post by post type and category, i have code like this, but it isint working properly:

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=999&post_type=posttypename&cat=categoryname' ); while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); $i = 1; ?>
```

This code displaying post from "posttypename", but it displays all post from that custom post type, but i need to displaying post from only "categoryname"

The whole code looks like this:

```
 <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=999&post_type=posttypename%cat=categoryname' ); while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); $i = 1; ?> <?php if($i == 1) : ?> <div class="">content of the post</div> <?php endif; ?> <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You lack `endwhile`, this is what is causing the error

Comment: I still not get it, i have endwhile in my loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) like this :

```
$catquery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'posttypename',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name'  => 'categoryname',
    // 'cat'         => cat ID here
));
if( $catquery->have_posts() ){
    while($catquery->have_posts()){
        $catquery->the_post();
        // your stuff
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i dont understand that, when i paste this code, the whole page is destroyed.

My all code looks like that:

  <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=999&post_type=posttypename%cat=categoryname' ); while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); $i = 1; ?>
 
    <?php if($i == 1) : ?>
    <div class="">content of the post</div>

  <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

How can i develop your code into that loop?

Comment: Your first code is working, i was delete endwhile, and now all works

Comment: i pas te the that code and modyfing it like this:

'<?php $catquery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'posttypename',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name'  => 'categoryname',
    // 'cat'         => cat ID here
));
if( $catquery->have_posts() ){
    while($catquery->have_posts()){
        $catquery->the_post();
        // your stuff
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
<content post>
<?php endwhile; ?>'

But it display only one post

Comment: `<content post>` should be just after `$catquery->the_post();`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php 
$catquery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'posttypename',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name'  => 'categoryname'    
));
if( $catquery->have_posts() ){
    $i = 1; 
    while($catquery->have_posts()){
        if($i == 1){ ?>
            <div class="">content of the post</div> 
        <?php } ?> 
        $i++; 
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```